# auto in function parameter list implying template argument

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++14

In his [talk at cppcon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwXq5MqY2ZA) (~13 mins in), Andrew Sutton mentions that you will "soon" be able to write

```
auto func(auto a, auto b) { ... }
```

which will be taken to mean

```
template <typename T, typename U> auto func(T a, U b) { ... }
```

just as was introduced for generic lambdas in C++14.

1. What is the name for this feature?
2. Is this a part of Concepts Lite, or was it proposed separately?
3. This obviously didn't make it into C++14 if it was indeed proposed; if anybody knows, what were the objections raised against it?

Comment: You can write this in GCC as an extension. [`Live example`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38bef5ed2f92c361)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Abbreviated Function Templates
2. Yes, it's part of Concepts Lite
3. It's in the concepts TS, which was nowhere near being ready for C++14.

Read all about it in [the latest draft of the concepts TS](https://github.com/cplusplus/concepts-ts/blob/master/concepts.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Though I have to say the name "generic functions" seems a bit, well, generic...

Comment: @TristanBrindle It *used* to be "generic functions", by extension of the name "generic lambdas." I forgot that the more recent versions of the TS have been using the name "abbreviated function" instead. Probably for exactly the reason you specify.

Comment: @TristanBrindle ...and now it's known as an [Abbreviated Function Template](https://github.com/cplusplus/concepts-ts/commit/421e2780a4887ee2920484894f59a1a851ac7ddb).

Comment: [tag:abbreviated-function-template] cannot be a tag, max 25 characters :(  Maybe [tag:abbreviated-template]